# Retrofit 2 Calls Override

Tags: java, design-patterns, overloading, retrofit2

All the examples that i have seen online about retrofit 2 include an interface which has the different urls to make the call to.

I have done the same in the form of.

```
@GET("NewsFeed/latest")
Observable<ArrayList<News>> getNews(@Query("category") int category,
                                    @Query("language") int language,
                                    @Query("location") int location,
                                    @Query("poster") int poster,
                                    @Query("limit") int limit,
                                    @Query("offset") long offset);
```

All the parameters in that call are optional so the call can be made even if none of the parameters are specified.Is there a way i can do that other than overloading the method?
Should i use the @nullable annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@QueryMap`. This allows us to specify query in a `Map`and new query parameters can be easily added without modifying existing code.

```
@GET("NewsFeed/latest")
Observable<ArrayList<News>>getNews(
            @QueryMap Map<String, String> options);
```

Usages:

```
private void fetchNews() {  
    Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put("category", "Sports");
    data.put("language", String.valueOf(2));

    // simplified call
    newsService.getNews(data);
}
```

Refer [this for more details](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-add-multiple-query-parameter-with-querymap)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-optional-query-parameters), query parameters are optional. By passing null to the method, retrofit ignores the query parameter.

(Maybe you shouldn't use primitive classes)